# List inserting and mutation

Tags: python, list

```
def new_insert(lst, i, e):
    lst = lst[:i] + [e] + lst[i:]
    
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
new_insert(a, 5, 5)
#Expected output: a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    
b = ['0', '1', '0']
new_insert(b, 0, '1')
#Expected output: b = ['1', '0', '1', '0']

    
new_insert([1,2,3], 1, 0)
#Expected output = None
```

For the above code, I am unable to get the answer for the newly modified list when adding e into the list. When e = 0, the output should return None. How can I change the code, so that I can get my expected output?

Comment: I don't see any line that would produce an output.

Comment: I think you mean that `lst[:] = lst[:i] + [e] + lst[i:]` if you can't return the list

Comment: thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre, your answer worked and answers all the output. Why is there a need to declare as lst[:]?

Comment: check the duplicate link I closed the question with

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**:

You need to return the modified list from `new_insert`:

```py
def new_insert(lst, i, e):
    return lst[:i] + [e] + lst[i:]
```

And then do:

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
a = new_insert(a, 5, 5)
```

**Option 2**:

Or just do:

```py
def new_insert(lst, i, e):
    lst[:] = list[:i] + [e] + lst[i:]
```

if you don't want to return it from the function.

Comment: changing to lst[:] works perfectly fine as it answers all the expected output. why is there a need to put lst[:]?

Comment: WIth the code you did, the function `new_insert` creates a _local_ variable named `lst`, which is destroyed when the function exits, without saving you changes. Doing `lst[:]` actually tells python to change the list you passed to the function and not  to create a copy of it.

Comment: there's a much better option here actually: `lst[i:i] = e` when e is a list

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it fails with `TypeError: can only assign an iterable`

Comment: ah then just `lst.insert(i,e)`. This is the fastest way

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know if he can use functions of list... anyway, all options will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return lst but also have an if condition and return none

```
def new_insert(lst, i, e):
    if (e == 0):
        return None

    lst = lst[:i] + [e] + lst[i:]

    return lst

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
print(new_insert(a, 5, 5))
#Expected output: a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

b = ['0', '1', '0']
print(new_insert(b, 0, '1'))
#Expected output: b = ['1', '0', '1', '0']


print(new_insert([1,2,3], 1, 0))
#Expected output = None
```